# How to have function with parameters inside bash test [

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, sh

Suppose I have a function foo which takes two parameters and returns true or false, I would like to use it within the test [ command in bash, some thing like this

```
param1=one
param2=two
if [ foo $param1 $param2 ]; then
    do something
fi
```

I know this works with out using `[]` like this,

```
if foo $param1 $param2; then .....
```

But I want to use it with in `[]`.

Comment: What do you want, the output code of the command or what it returns?

Comment: If it works without the brackets (using the exit status), then there is no need to run in with the `test` command.

Comment: **Why** do you want to use it inside `test`? Are you trying to test whether it emits output, rather than its exit status?

Comment: I am trying to understand how `test` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test whether the *exit status* of your command indicates success or failure, leave off the brackets entirely; using the `test` command in that use case is wrong, full-stop.

In this case,

```
if foo "$param1" "$param2"; then ...; fi
```

is the only correct syntax that isn't needlessly inefficient.

---

It's certainly *possible* to emit `$?` inside your subprocess, and check the output of that using `test`, like so:

```
if [ "$(foo "$param1" "$param2" >&2; echo "$?")" -eq 2 ]; then ...; fi
```

...but see again re: "needlessly inefficient"; this would be better written as:

```
foo "$param1" "$param2"; retval=$?
if [ $retval -eq 2 ]; then ...; fi
```

...avoiding all the overhead of an unnecessary subshell.

---

If you want to test whether the *output* of your command is non-empty (typically an undesirable / unnecessary operation, as most standard UNIX commands can indicate whether they operated correctly, whether they found what they were searching for, etc. via exit status):

```
if [ -n "$(foo "$param1" "$param2")" ]; then ...; fi
```

is correct.

---

One important thing to keep in mind -- any use of `$()` moves your function from running inside of the parent shell (and thus able to update or modify that shell's state) into a subshell. So -- if your function is supposed to change variables or state inside the shell, using `$()` will modify its behavior.

Answer (score 2):

[`test`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_test.htm) or `[ ]` evaluates expressions, not the *exit status* of a function.

To evaluate the exit status of a *function* / *command*, use `if` in the way you're using it:

```
if foo "$param1" "$param2"; then .....
```